# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los días de la semana por separado y ordenarlos por día?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta sentencia

```
SELECT total, DAYOFWEEK(fecha_hora) as dia 
FROM ventas 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`fecha_hora`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
ORDER BY `dia` ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que me devuelve los registros creados en la semana y con el día en que se creo con una representación en números...

¿Cómo puedo hacer para sumar los registros dependiendo de su día y mostrarlos ordenadamente?

Por ejemplo... quiero mostrar en un campo lunes la suma de todos los registros en el que día es igual a 2, mostrar en un campo martes la suma de todos los registros en el que día es igual a 3 y así sucesivamente...

El resultado debería visualizarse así:

```
`Domingo, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado`
`200,     100,   200,    500,       300,    100,     120
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente consulta podria servirte de referencia si usas MySQL

```
SELECT 
   DAYNAME(date) day
  ,COUNT(*) total 
FROM 
   table_name 
WHERE 
   YEAR(date) = 2019
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY total ASC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho... pero lo modifique un poco `SELECT 
   DAYNAME(fecha_hora) day
  ,SUM(total) total
FROM 
   ventas 
WHERE (WEEK(fecha_hora) = WEEK(NOW())) 
   AND (YEAR(fecha_hora) = YEAR(NOW()))
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY total DESC`